# Configure server functioning as VPN so that client is able to use internet

Tags: ubuntu, server, openvpn

I'm doing [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04) tutorial on how to set up an OpenVPN Server on Ubuntu. I have followed all the steps and I have managed to connect to the VPN from my local computer using [tunnelblick](https://tunnelblick.net/downloads.html). Since I want to reroute all the client's traffic through the VPN, I used the following settings in the `server.conf` file on the OpenVPN server (explained in step 5 of the tutorial):

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
```

However when I use these settings, I'm not able to connect to the internet. When I change these settings to

```
;push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
```

I am able to connect the internet after connecting to the VPN, but I'm not redirecting my traffic through the VPN (which is, again, what I want). I'm sure that traffic is not redirected through the VPN, since https://www.dnsleaktest.com/ gives the same ip address when I'm logged in to the VPN as when I'm not. The VPN's log in tunnelblick looks like this:

```
2018-11-21 12:58:46 Initialization Sequence Completed
2018-11-21 12:58:46 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1542801526,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.8.0.6,my_server_ip,1194,,
2018-11-21 12:59:26 *Tunnelblick: After 30.0 seconds, gave up trying to fetch IP address information using the ipInfo host's name after connecting.
2018-11-21 13:00:01 *Tunnelblick: An error occured fetching IP address information using the ipInfo host's IP address after connecting
```

I don't think my issues have something to do with firewall, although I'm not sure. I'm using an amazon server to function as OpenVPN server and I have the following inbound settings:

[image]

and the following outbound settings:

[image]

**Question:** How do I configure the OpenVPN server correctly so that the client's traffic will be redirected through the VPN *and* the client is able to use the internet?